# How is shiny::markRenderFunction used?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

The question [How can I change the size of rgl plots in Shiny RMarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009133/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-rgl-plots-in-shiny-rmarkdown) discusses the fact that it's hard to set the size of an `rglwidget` in a dynamic R Markdown document.  The issue is that the Shiny output function sets the size, but there's no obvious way to pass any arguments to it, so the default 512 x 512 size is always used.

The `rgl::renderRglwidget` function is written according to the example in `htmlwidgets::shinyRenderWidget`, which provides no way to pass output arguments:

```
rglwidgetOutput <- function(outputId, width = '512px', height = '512px'){
  shinyWidgetOutput(outputId, 'rglWebGL', width, height, package = 'rgl')
}

renderRglwidget <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
  if (!quoted) { expr <- substitute(expr) } # force quoted
  shinyRenderWidget(expr, rglwidgetOutput, env, quoted = TRUE)
}
```

It appears from the `shiny` documentation that it should be using `shiny::markRenderFunction` to allow for `outputArgs` to be passed in, but there are no examples that I can find.

What should `renderRglwidget` look like to make use of `shiny::markRenderFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is fairly simple, though there may be a few caveats.
The `rglwidgetOutput` function was fine as it was, but `renderRglwidget` needed to be modified to

```
renderRglwidget <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE, 
                            outputArgs = list()) {
  if (!quoted) { expr <- substitute(expr) } # force quoted
  markRenderFunction(rglwidgetOutput,
                     shinyRenderWidget(expr, rglwidgetOutput, env, quoted = TRUE),
                     outputArgs = outputArgs)
}
```

The linked question [How can I change the size of rgl plots in Shiny RMarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009133/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-rgl-plots-in-shiny-rmarkdown) has been edited to show how this is used.

The caveats:  setting `outputArgs = list(height = "auto")` appears to choose zero height rather than the remaining window height.  `width = "auto"` does appear to work *after* a window resize; before
the resize, it looks too big.  Similarly, using percentage values for
`width` or `height` are unsatisfactory.  Specifying integer values
or strings with `px` units (e.g. `width = "300px"`) look fine.